# "Enable Multiple Windows" setting for an iOS 13 app (iPhone only)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, uiscenedelegate

I'm aware that the new `info.plist` file has some new `Application Scene Manifest` entry as of `XCode 11` and `iOS 13` only projects, however, what's the benefit of having `Enable Multiple Windows` option in this manifest, if I only choose that my app is only for iPhone ? giving that the multi-window app experience is only available for iPad apps only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An app whose target device is only iPhone can still run on iPad. So, `Enable Multiple Windows` will matter when your app is running on iPad.

Answer (score 1):

> Enable Multiple Windows option in this manifest

The *option* needs to be there, but its *value* will usually be NO.